# How to reset form to last saved(through ajax) stage

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jqueryform

The thing is I'm using `jQuery("form")[0].reset();` to reset a form whenever required. This method is resetting form to its initial stage. Here initial stage means, "the stage when form was loaded into the page for first time with some values".

**But what I need is to reset the form to last saved stage.**

**What I'm doing:** Saving form data through `jQuery.ajax({----});` without any page refresh.

**What is target:** After saving form data with an `ajax` request, if user change any other values in form but don't want to save it and opt to reset form to last saved value. How to achieve that? Because `reset();` will reset form to initial values.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: it's either you use cookie or `$_GET`

Comment: in the success function save the data of the form in a variable, whan the people push the reset button append the values from that variable to the inputs instead of reseting the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys.

I tried to implement a solution based on **madalin ivascu**'s comment. Also found a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luken/4VVs3/) to do the same. With some modifications/changes I got what I needed.

**Step 1:** Write a custom plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.deserialize = function (serializedString) {
        var form = jQuery(this);
        form[0].reset();
        serializedString = serializedString.replace(/\+/g, "%20");
        var formFieldArray = serializedString.split("&");
        jQuery.each(formFieldArray, function(i, pair) {
            var nameValue = pair.split("=");
            var name = decodeURIComponent(nameValue[0]);
            var value = decodeURIComponent(nameValue[1]);

            var field = form.find("[name='" + name + "']");
            if (field[0] != undefined) {
                if (field[0].type == "radio" || field[0].type == "checkbox") {
                    var fieldWithValue = field.filter('[value="' + value + '"]');
                    var isFound = (fieldWithValue.length > 0);
                    if (!isFound && value == "on") {
                        field.first().prop("checked", true);
                    } else {
                        fieldWithValue.prop("checked", isFound);
                    } 
                } else {
                    field.val(value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

**Step 2:** Save serialized form data somewhere.

When you need to reset form to last saved stage, use this:

```
yourForm.deserialize(serializedFormData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say below your form structure something like below:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" id="recordID" value="">
   // Put your other HTML elements here
   <input type="button" id="save" value="Save">
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Now when you save the form via ajax on the `success` event of that add the `id` of the record that you just saved in the `#recordID` field.

Now you have to do the trick when you click on the reset button:

```
$('#reset').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   if($('#recordID').val() != '') { // if id present then form is in edit mode
        //Do an ajax call by passing id and pull all date and populate in your form fields
   } else {
       //Form is in add mode because no id is present, just reset the form
   }
});
```

Hope this will helps you!